# Getting values of multiple checkboxes and inserting them into MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to look on SO for a solution similar to mine and I couldn't find anything.

I have 4 checkboxes on my website

```
<label class="control-label" for="last_name"><strong>Filtering Options</strong> </label>
<div style='color: #777; font-size: 16px;'><td  class='text-center'> <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='city_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_city value="location_city"/> </td> City </div>
<div style='color: #777; font-size: 16px;'><td  class='text-center'> <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='county_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_county value="location_zip"/> </td> County </div>
<div style='color: #777; font-size: 16px;'><td  class='text-center'> <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='region_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_region value="location_region"/> </td> Region </div>
<div style='color: #777; font-size: 16px;'><td  class='text-center'> <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='country_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_country value="location_country"/>   </td> Country</div>
```

What I want to do is whenever ANY of them is clicked, I want to cycle through all of them, seem which ones are checked, get their values and update the MySQL based on the selections. I'm pretty sure I will be fine with the PHP/MySQL part but I am struggling with the jQuery to get the values.

Lets take this as an example. Checkbox 1 and 3 are selected, 2 and 4 are not. I only want to post the values of checkbox 1 and 3. Then if checkbox 2 is added to the selection, I want to post values of checkbox 1, 2 and 3.

This is what I have tried so far. It reacts when I click on any checkbox but I'm just unsure as to how I go about getting specific values.

```
$('.filters').on('ifClicked', function(event)
    {
        var temp_id         =   event.target.id;
        current_cb_element  =   temp_id;
        var chckValue = $('#' + current_cb_element).parent('[class*="icheckbox"]').hasClass("checked");
        if (chckValue)
            chckValue = 0;
        else
            chckValue = 1;

        $("input[name=filters]").each( function () {

            alert( chckValue );
   });
```

Comment: which plugin are you using? I may assume icheck, but I'm not sure. Please add more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
                var arrayCheck = new Array();
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i) {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                        arrayCheck.push(i + 1);
                    }

                });
            });
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but this is what I get when I check the array [link](http://prntscr.com/ktyg0j) and I'm not sure what does values correspond to?

Comment: i have updated the code, please try now and no. refers the index plus 1 of checkbox, say if first checkbox is check link arrayCheck[0]:1

Comment: Ok so two questions. 
1. Is there a way to put a value into the array, rather than just a number? 
2. I have more than just those 4 checkboxes on the page. Can I change input[type="checkbox"] to input[name="xyz"]?

Comment: 1. Pushing values to an array is a standard way, u can use string i.e (concatenate string) 

2. this code will work for all the checkboxes on the page and you can also use input[name="xyz"]

Comment: Got you. Almost working but I am having one more issue. The data seems to be one click behind. Please see [this](http://prntscr.com/ktyvei) link for array associated with each checkbox setting. As you can see, the first checkbox click doesn't input anything into an array. Why is that the case?

Comment: I have put the code with checkboxes and the jQuery on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cXDuxth5)

Comment: @artlemaks, i have checked and tested your code and it seems working fine at my end. Can you please save your changes again and refresh the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180001/discussion-between-artlemaks-and-uttam-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

Check for the checked attribute on the checkbox and if found read the value.

```
$("input[name=filters]").each(function() {
                if($(this).attr('checked')){
            console.log($(this).val());
        }
      });
```

Comment: There is no reaction in console when I use this code and press the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

if you have option for jQuery, then why not. Just take the parent, find all targets to attach some event, and reiterate values in that event.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#checkboxes [type='checkbox']").change(function(ev){
      console.clear()
      $("#checkboxes [type='checkbox']:checked").map((index, cb)=> {
            console.log(cb.value)
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='city_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_city value="location_city"/>
 <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='county_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_county value="location_zip"/>
 <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='region_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_region value="location_region"/>
 <input type='checkbox' name="filters" id='country_checkbox' class='checkbox filters' $lstr_completed_country value="location_country"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest I got to a working answer. I replaced the first line as it wouldn't work for me and got
`$('.filters').on('ifClicked', function(event)
 {
  $("#checkboxes [type='checkbox']:checked").map((index, cb)=> {
            console.log(cb.value)
      });
   });`
Which updates the data but the selection always seems to be one click behind. So I need to click 2 boxes at least before getting a return